# How can I diff between HEAD and the n-th last revision that changed a file?

Tags: git, git-diff

If I want to see the differences in a single file between 2 commits, I can run something like

```
git diff HEAD..HEAD~3 -- file
```

Unfortunately, if that particular file didn't change between those commits, that command is useless. If I dont want to use `gitk`, I'd have to look up the commits with

```
git log -- pathto/file
```

then manually pass those commits to to `git diff`.

Is there some kind of trick that incorporates history simplification to enable using some kind of simplified syntax like `HEAD~3` to refer to the 3rd previous commit that changed that particular file, rather than just the 3rd previous commit?

Answer (score 1):

### An alias for diffing between HEAD and the last n-th revision of a path

I've come up with an alias called `ndiff`. Running

```sh
git ndiff <number> <path>
```

shows the difference between the `<n>`-th last revision (in topological order) that changed `<path>` (which may be a file or a directory). To define this alias, make the script executable, put it on your search path, and then run

```sh
git config --global alias.ndiff '! git-ndiff'
```

#### Example

Here is a test of the alias in one of my repositories. As in your repository, the last three commits didn't change the `README` file:

```sh
$ git log HEAD~3..HEAD -- README
$
```

However, with my `ndiff` alias, I can diff against the 3rd last commit that changed `README`, like so:

```sh
$ git ndiff 3 README
diff --git a/README b/README
index d482a72..5b6d0b5 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -10,4 +10,5 @@ LaTeX & friends. Three predefined styles, one of which closely mimicks that
 of the Matlab editor, are available and can be invoked by listings macros
 and environments in conjunction with (most) options provided by the listings
 package. The appearance of your Matlab listings can be further tweaked via a
-key-value interface extending that of listings’.
+key-value interface extending that of listings'. Partial support for Octave
+syntax is provided.
$
```

Happy days!

### Script

(The script is available at [Jubobs/git-aliases](https://github.com/Jubobs/git-aliases) on GitHub.)

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# git-ndiff.sh
#
# Usage: git ndiff <n> <path>
#
# Show changes between the n-th revision that changed <path> and HEAD
#
# To make a Git alias called 'ndiff' out of this script,
# put the latter on your search path, make it executable, and run
#
#   git config --global alias.ndiff '! git-ndiff'


ndifferror(){
    printf "usage: git ndiff <n> <path>\n"
    printf "where <n> is a positive integer\n"
    exit 1
}

# Check that two arguments were passed
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    ndifferror
fi

# Check that the first argument is a positive integer
if [ "$1" -gt 0 ] >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    n=$1
else
    ndifferror
fi

# Check that the second argument is an existing path
if [ -e $2 ]; then
    path="$2"
else
    exit 0
fi

# Get the revision of interest
nthrev=$(git log --follow --pretty=format:%H -- $path | sed -n "$n""p")
# Note: unfortunately, the "--follow" functionality is only provided by the
# porcelain command "git log", and not by any plumbing command (Git 2.3.3)

# Show changes of interest
if [ -n "$nthrev" ]
then
    git diff $nthrev -- $path
else
    exit 0
fi

exit $?
```

Comment: No need to create an alias; as long as the script is in a directory on the `$PATH`, it will be executed when calling `git ndiff`.

Comment: @mipadi I know but, because I also have an alias for listing aliases, I need to define all my aliases as "proper" Git aliases.